# Power Query Possible matches

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have Two tables in PowerQuery, I need to be able to find possible matches between the two. what I mean is a little complicated, so I will explain it in more detail.

The reason this is important is because there are 1,000+ files in the system which need to be accounted for. I have a master list of all of the valid files in the system. There are several that may be missing information and being able to have a table with possible matches will speed up corrections

One table contains a column populated by names of files and some data from said files. Another Table has information pulled from a Database (of which I do not have access, I can only read data)

The odd of having multiple matches are very low, so that is not a concern.

This is for Excel 2010, and it is using PowerQuery

Text.Contains()

List.Contains()

[Before And After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dfDn.jpg)

What would be best is if there could be some sort of substring function to determine if a value is a possible match, and return possibly matching value.
This does not have to be perfect, it is just meant to help as much as possible.

p.s. I apologize for not being able to embed my picture into my post, but i do not have enough reputation for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below assumes you want to perform a case insensitive check for a substring, which may (or may not) be present anywhere in the main string.

```
let
    firstTable = Table.FromColumns({{"***.xlsx", "###.xlsx", "$$$.xlsx", "@@@.xlsx"}, {"ASDFS", "ASFSZW", "L;ASDF", "RAWRSS"}}, type table [FILE = text, DATA = text]),
    secondTable = Table.FromColumns({{"ASDF", "ASF", "L;A", "SDA"}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, type table [DATA = text, VALUE = number]),
    buffered = Table.Buffer(secondTable),
    thirdTable = Table.AddColumn(firstTable, "$toExpand", (first) => Table.SelectRows(secondTable, each Text.Contains(first[DATA], [DATA], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)), type table),
    expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(thirdTable, "$toExpand", {"DATA", "VALUE"}, {"POSSIBLE MATCH", "VALUE"})
in
    expanded
```

All matches are returned, meaning it's possible to end up with more rows than you started with. Multiple matches (in your example) are highlighted below.

[image: Output table]

Comment: Thanks, That works perfectly, also having more rows than I started with is acceptable, it is more a matter of making it easier to add in the data when someone edits the file. Your Solution was also easy to adjust to correctly apply to the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

You may use following approach:

```
let
    Table1 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Table2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    add = Table.AddColumn(Table1, "Table2", (z)=> Table.SelectRows(Table2, each Text.StartsWith(z[DATA],[DATA])){0}?),
    expand = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(add, "Table2", {"DATA", "VALUE"}, {"MATCH", "VALUE"})
in
    expand
```

[image]

As per your example, matching was checked by start of string. If there were two or more corresponding rows in Table2, first row was kept. Of cource, you may implement different logic.